# Возврат конкретного типа, а не object в функции десериализации

Tags: c#, сериализация, десериализация

Не важно, откуда сериализуем, из файла или строки, мы в любом случае в нашей функции передаём некоторый тип (**`Type type`**), чтобы знать, что десериализовать.

Сейчас у меня результат функции - это `object`, а я уже дальше его преобразовываю к конкретному типу.

Но можно ли сделать сразу, чтобы функция возвращала тип T, чтобы избавится от приведения типов?

UPD: в общем сделал, как хотел.

```
 public static T BinReadFromString<T>(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    return default(T);

                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    return (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Tracks.StackTrace("Base64: {0}. Type: {1}. Error: {2}", value, typeof(T), ex.ToString());
            }

            return default(T);
        }



  public static T GetSerialized<T>(string key, bool newInstanceOnNull = true)
        {
            string value = PlayerPrefs.GetString(key, null);
            T result = SerializationUtils.BinReadFromString<T>(value);

            if (result == null && newInstanceOnNull)
                result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            return result;
        }
```

Но меня смущает, что во второй функции идёт проверка на null, но ведь не всегда default(T) возвращает null? Или всегда?

Comment: Приведите примеры кода, пожалуйста. Как сейчас, и как хочется.

Comment: @ Petr Abdulin обновил первый пост

Comment: Не всегда. Добавьте ограничение `where T: class` и тогда будет всегда. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Вы про generics? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.120).aspx

```
public T GetResult<T>(object obj)
{
    return (T) obj;
}

public void Main()
{
     var v = GetResult<int>("123");
}
```

В Вашем случае default не всегда возвращает null

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.120).aspx

> При заданной переменной t параметризованного типа T оператор t = null
>   действителен, если только T является ссылочным типом, а t = 0 будет
>   справедливо только для числовых типов значений, но не для структур.
>   Решением является использование ключевого слова default, которое
>   вернет значение null для ссылочных типов и "0" — для числовых типов
>   значений. Для структур оно вернет каждого члена со значением "0" или
>   null в зависимости от их типа — тип значения или ссылочный тип. Для
>   типов, допускающих значение null, ключевое слово default вернет
>   значение Nullable, которое инициализируется как любая структура.

Вы можете ограничить тип T (как было замечено в коментариях), что бы он мог быть скажем только классом/каким либо интерфэйсом и таким образом добиться что бы было всегда null:

```
public T GetResult<T>(object obj) where T : IDisposable
{
    return (T)obj;
}

public T GetResult<T>(object obj) where T : class
{
    return (T)obj;
}

public T GetResult<T>(object obj) where T : Program
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

или же можете проверять так:

```
if(result == default(T))
{
    //...
}
```

Я бы сделал как то так. но не в курсе Вашей задачи:

```
public static T BinReadFromString<T>(string value) where T : class
        {
            //code..
            return default(T);
        }

        public static T GetSerialized<T>(string key, bool newInstanceOnNull = true) where T: class
        {
            string value = "test";

            if (newInstanceOnNull)
            {
                return BinReadFromString<T>(value) ?? Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            }
            return BinReadFromString<T>(value);
        }
```

Comment: @ AiSatan обновил первый пост